# Getting error about a stray start tag that I simply can't figure out

Tags: html

There's an edit at the bottom:

I have this code:

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="">Select Month</option> 
    <option value='http://www.example.com?m=201512'>
    <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;">
        December 2015 &nbsp;(4)
    </span>
    </option>
</select>
```

When I inspect the HTML with Firebug, the span tag is not there. If I look at the page source, via Firefox, the span start tag and end tag are displayed in red indicating that something is wrong.

Hovering the cursor over the red code gives me: Stray start tag "span"

If I run the page through a validator, no errors are found.

Perhaps a span tag is not allowed in a option tag???

But then, why doesn't the validator not flag it???

EDIT * * * * 
NIX THE BIT ABOUT THE VALIDATOR, I just looked again and found I was using the CSS validator.

I ran the page through the markup vaidator and got:

> Error: Stray start tag span.
>
> From line 273, column 80; to line 273, column 134
>
> m=201512'><span style="text-decoration: underline; color:
>   blue;"> Decem

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to find a different validator if it passes that HTML.

Comment: `span` tags are absolutely not valid inside an `option`/`select`. Use CSS on `select option.some-class` where you give the option a class with that name.

Comment: I edited my question - I was using the CSS validator instead of the markup validator. The problem was flagged by the markup validator.  As to putting a class on the option tag, I'm don't battle with a Wordpress function which creates the option tag and does not give me the the option to include something in the option tag. I'll look around and see if there is another way to accomplish the task. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [MDN Option:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)
>
> **Permitted content** Text with eventually escaped characters (like é).

No spans are permitted, it is text only. If you want to style the text, you need to look at a JavaScript/CSS solution that is not a standard element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element

Comment: I added an edit,at the bottom, to my question, it is at the end of the question. It corrects my comments about the validator. I'll try to come up with a way to do what I want - the option tag is generated by a Wordpress function and I can't add anything in the option tag, like a class. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I'm looking for other ways to create the select where I can code the actual option tags. If that fails, I'll use some JavaScript onload and change the option tags textDecoration and color styles

Answer (score 0):

`span` tags are absolutely not valid inside an `option`/`select`.

Use CSS with the selector

```
select option.some-class {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
```

where `some-class` is the name you give the class for the option, ie;

```
<option class="some-class">December 2015 &nbsp;(4)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *epascarello* and *worldofjr* for explaining the error was occurring because span tags are not allowed in option tags. It appears that no tags are allowed in an option tag.

I thought of a way around the problem -

The select I'm coding is for a list of Wordpress archive months. The function wp_get_archives() has an option to generate option tags for each entry but there is no way I can add to the option tags, to put in the styling I want.

I want all but the first option in the select to have color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; (I want them to look like a link. I know they won't change color when hovered or followed, but blue and underling and the pointer cursor should get across that they are links.)

The function does not generate the select tag, I have to code that and so I can add to it. I put class="optionSetRules" on the select.

I coded the class as:

```
.optionSetRules option {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

That will style the option tags, inside the parent with class="optionSetRules"

I coded the first option in the select myself, to display "Select Month." I don't want that option to have color: blue; and text-decoration: underline; so I added class="optionSetBlackNoUnderline" to the option tag and then added this CSS:

```
.optionSetBlackNoUnderline{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

That coding gives me what I want - the options, except the first one, set to color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;

Now the question is, which answer do I mark as the accepted answer???

SimonT